# Prove certain ring is noetherian.

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, commutative-algebra, noetherian

> Let $R$ be a commutative ring with the property that for each nonzero ideal $I$ and
> element $a ∈ I$ there exists a unique ideal $J$ such that $IJ = (a)$. Show that $R$ is
> Noetherian.

I am looking for some elementary proof to use really basic ring and generators property to solve the problem.

My attempt is to show $J$ is finitely generated and use $IJ=JI$ to show $I$ is finitely generated.

I suppose for $a\in I$, there exists $b_1,b_2,...,b_n$, such that $\sum_{i=1}^na_ib_i=a$ for some $a_i\in I$, where $n$ is the minimal number of such kind of summation holds. I decided to show $J=(b_1,b_2,...,b_n)$ such that $IJ=(a)$. But I couldn't go further, any hint or suggestions are appreciated. Thanks.

Edit: The assumption that for *all* $a\in I$, there exists a unique $J$, such that $IJ=(a)$ is used in this proof. If it is not the case, we can't conclude that for the same $a\in I\cap J$, $IJ=JI=(a)$.

Comment: that is a good starting point, but why there should be a finite number of such $b_i$'s?

Comment: @DavideTrono This is directly followed by the definition of product of rings

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You already seem to have what you were asking for.

Starting from where you left off, let $J’=(b_1,\ldots,b_n)$.   Then $(a)=IJ\supseteq IJ’\supseteq (a)$.  Thus we have equality all across.  By uniqueness of $J$ then, $J=J’$ is finitely generated.

(I haven’t gone further because you indicated this is the subproblem you wanted to settle.)

Comment: But why $(a)=IJ\supset IJ'$? I firstly thought that there may be an ideal generated by more than $n$ elements contained in $J$ and such chain of ideals may not be finite.

Comment: @Minglingmaster $IJ\supseteq IJ’$ because $J\supseteq J’$.  I don’t know what chain of ideals you are thinking of, because $J’$ is already equal to $J$…

Comment: @Minglingmaster “unique ideal J such that $IJ=(a)$” means if there is another ideal A such that $IA=(a)$, then $J=A$.

Comment: I know how to use uniqueness, but I just don't undersatnd why $IJ\supset IJ'$ and $J\supset J'$. Since I deduced $IJ'\supset (a)$, I was thinking of finding the ideals contained in $J'$ whose product with $I$ satisfies the assumptions in which sense one might create a chain of ideals.

Comment: @Minglingmaster ok… but the containment is clear now, right? (As per my comment above?)

Comment: @rscwieb Actually, I can't see why $J$ must contain $J'$ and why $IJ\supset IJ'$. The containment is the only thing that I got stuck. I mean I think the generators of $J$ may have nothing to do with those of $J'$'s.

Comment: @Minglingmaster The definition of $IJ$ means that for any element $a$ in it, $a=\sum_{i=0}^n a_ib_i$ where $a_i\in I$ and $b_i\in J$ and $n$ is some nonnegative integer.  So all the $b_i$ are in J. The ideal generated by any subset of J of course has to be contained in J.

Comment: @rscwieb. But $a$ can be written in more than one way like that. Suppose $a=\sum_{j=0}^m c_jd_j$, and we don't know the relationship between $b_i$ and $d_j$. Maybe $J$ is the set formed by those $d$'s. In this case we don't need all $b_i$ are in $J$.

Comment: @Minglingmaster the $d_i$’s would be a second generating set.  That seems superfluous though. You only need ONE generating set. You don’t have to prove anything using more than one.

Comment: I think I understand what you mean. If so, it seems I don't need to suppose the minimal property holds for $n$, right? and the assumption of the problem don't need to assume it holds for every $a\in I$, we just need one $a$,is that so?

Comment: @rschwieb.Thanks for your patience. I found my original solution and I realized that I was a fool.

Comment: @Minglingmaster correct.  “Finitely generated “ just means “there exists a finite set generating it” and nothing about exactly how big it is.